# Make divs width oscillate between a given range before breaking on to new line?

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div with two children inside.

```
<div id="middleHolder">
  <a href="#">
     <img>
  </a>
  <div id="sidebar">
     <p>content</p>
  </div>
```

I want the a href to be floated left and be 100% of the image's size (655px X 506px).  I want the sidebar to be floated left and stay inline with the a href as long as it's width is between 33.5% and 27%.  Then, once the width is smaller, I want the div to break onto a new line and be 100%.
**Is there a way to make a divs width oscillate between a given range before having it break on to a new line without having to use multiple media queries?**

Below is the css:

```
#middleHolder > a {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 2% 2% 0;
  max-width: 655px;
  width: 100%;
  }

#socialMediaSidebar {
  float: left
  min-height: 506px;
  min-width: 270px;
  width: 27-33.5%;  /* Not accurate, but gives the idea of what I’m trying to accomplish */
  }

  @media width… /*unsure the specific size but would be inacted once socialMediaSidebar goes less then 270px. */

#socialMediaSidebar {
  width: 100%;
  }
```

Comment: Combine min-width and max-width to accomplish this. Perhaps like this? http://jsfiddle.net/e4j78ek6/

Comment: Oh my gosh, I can't believe the answer was that simple.  I've been trying to figure out this issue for 30 minutes to no avail.  Thank you, thank you, thank you!!!!

Comment: If you want to put your response as an answer I'll mark it as the accept answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize max-width and min-width together to ensure that it will stay within a given range. Based on the model, if the content will not fit, it should display: block and drop down a line if the given range will not fit in the flow of the document.

Example could be:

```
#test {
    min-width: 25%;
    max-width: 37%;
    background: #CBA;
}
```

As seen here:

http://jsfiddle.net/e4j78ek6/1/